# User inputed file to read from c++

Tags: c++, string, file, input

I'm trying to read from a file using type ifstream on the variable dnaInput. I want the program to be able to take what the user inputs and then read from the file they said. Input is of type string

```
cout<<"Would you like to continue? (Y/N)"<<endl;
cin>>input;
while(input=='y'||input=='Y')
{
    cout<<"input the name of your file you would like to append to the current bryce.out.txt file."<<endl;
    cout<<"MAKE SURE YOU INCLUDE THE .TXT"<<endl;
    cin>>DNASource;
    dnaInput.open(DNASource.c_str());
    while (dnaInput.fail())
{
    cerr<<"Error opening file!"<<endl;
    cout<<"input the name of your file you would like to append to the current bryce.out.txt file."<<endl;
    cout<<"MAKE SURE YOU INCLUDE THE .TXT (NO SPACES)"<<endl;
    cin>>DNASource;
    dnaInput.open(DNASource.c_str());
}
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? It is not clear here. Please provide more detail, exactly what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Abhijit I'm trying to take what the user inputs, for example "readme.txt" and use their input to open the file they please

Comment: OK, Once you open the file what do you want to do with that file? Read the file line by line and print it?

Comment: Quite often when using an [Integrated Development Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) the working directory (where the program is being run from) is not where you think it is. Writing a file to see where it winds up or the `getcwd` function may help you. So might using the `perror` function to print the error message.

Comment: What your program is behaving? Is not it find the file? Is your program keep continuously printing `"Error opening file!"1`

Comment: @Abhijit I'm trying to read from it line by line which gets called in a function below the second while statement, but everytime i run it i get the error that i created

Comment: @Abhijit exactly. it won't open the file but it doesnt continously print it (like it doesnt get stuck in a loop endlessly and print a millon of those to my screen)

Comment: It is very clear that file is not present where you are running the application. Can you provide me file path?

Answer (score 0):

Add one more string variable and modify your program like below

```
 std::string path="/yourpathtothefile/";

 cin>>DNASource;
 path = path + DNASource;
 dnaInput.open(path.c_str());
```